# How to stop sortable in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using
`$("#images").sortable();`
for sorting some image in small game for kids,I want to remove the sort-ability.
How to do that ??

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 $( ".selector" ).sortable( "disable" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was by using the same function with the attribute 'destroy'

```
$( "#images" ).sortable('destroy');
```